# Elastic Search performing slowly

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I am currently using Elastic Search version 2.4.4.

I am using a single node cluster where around 10 million data is stored.
Each document consists of around 12 fields (some analyzed, some not-analyzed).
Average document size is 1.5 kb.

We are using Multi-Search that consists of 6 search queries using Java API.

I have noted two different timings of Elastic Search:
1) The 'took' time in milliseconds (which is around '50ms' for each individual search query)
2) Total time taken by one Multi-Search request is around '1500ms' (I have calculated this time in Java API)

Why multi-search request time is so high as compared to the individual search queries?
Can you help me figure out the reason for the time difference?

Comment: Might be helpful to show the query that's giving you trouble.

Comment: You may want to check elasticsearch [profile api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-profile.html) to optimize your query.

Comment: the question is what are you measuring, took is pure calculation in the ES, while in Java api you may be count also http costs?